# Ansible dictionary: implicit evaluation of all values?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm a bit puzzled about Ansible behaviour: it looks like when I request a single key's value, it evaluates all values in the dictionary.

Here's my case. I have a dictionary with two keys: `dev` and `prod`. Each key's value is defined via a specific Jinja2 expression that involves decryption using AWS KMS. Roughly it looks like this:

```
mydict:
  dev: '{{ "dev-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt }}'
  prod: '{{ "prod-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt }}'
```

`kms_decrypt` is a custom filter that decrypts the ciphertext. Since `dev` and `prod` environments are separated, and the playbook runs within an encryption context valid for only one of these environments, **only one expression can be evaluated at a time**. Attempt to retrieve a value from the other key will fail.

So let's say the playbook runs in the context of `dev` environment, and when I evaluate `mydict['dev']`, I expect it to return decrypted `dev-ciphertext`. However, what I get in fact is failure on decryption of `prod-ciphertext`, because the encryption context does not match.

I can illustrate the same behaviour in a simpler example. Instead of recreating the decryption mechanism, I just defined one of the dictionary values via an undefined variable:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  vars:
    dev_value: '123'
    mydict:
     dev: '{{ dev_value }}'
     prod: '{{ prod_value }}'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict['dev'] }}"
```

Regardless of the fact that `mydict['prod']` is never explicitly queried, I still get an error indicating that it can't be evaluated:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'prod_value' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'ansible/test.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I realize that there are a lot of ways to work around this problem, but can anyone explain why does the whole dictionary values get evaluated when only a single key is queried? It doesn't seem to make sense to me - at least from performance point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja templates are rendered in all circumstances -- there is no such thing as "lazy jinja," only lazy tasks via the `when:` or similar guards

So if you don't already have `my_dict["dev"]` scattered all over your code, then I would suggest using a reasonable name like `my_env` or something, and only declare the one value that is meaningful for the active environment:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  vars:
    dev_value: '123'
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      my_env: '{{ "prod-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt }}'
    when: some_environment_variable == "prod"
  - set_fact:
      my_env: '{{ "dev-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt }}'
    when: some_environment_variable == "dev"
```

Otherwise, you can guard the expressions -- which for clarity are **always going to be evaluated** -- to return defaults if they are not applicable:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  vars:
    dev_value: '123'
    my_dict:
      prod: '{{ ("prod-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt)
               if the_magic_env == "prod" else {} }}'
      dev: '{{ ("dev-ciphertext" | kms_decrypt)
               if the_magic_env == "dev" else {} }}'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict['dev'] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation and suggested workarounds!